# Having trouble with WebMock, not stubbing correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, controller, webmock

**Ruby 1.9.3, RSpec 2.13.0, WebMock 1.17.4, Rails 3**

I am writing tests for a company app. The controller in question displays a table of a customer's placed calls, and allows for sort/filter options.

**EDIT** The test fails because with my current setup, the path does not render, because the `recorder_server` is either not running locally, OR not setup correctly. Please help with this, too.

```
A Errno::ECONNREFUSED occurred in recordings#index:
Connection refused - connect(2)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `initialize'

-------------------------------
Request:
-------------------------------
* URL       : http://www.recorder.example.com:8080/recorded_calls
* IP address: 127.0.0.1
* Parameters: {"controller"=>"recordings", "action"=>"index"}
* Rails root: /var/www/rails/<repository>
```

1. As a call is placed, its data joins an xml file, **created by an external API, called *Recorder***
2. The *RecordingsController* takes the xml file, and parses it into a hash.
3. When you visit the associated path, you see the results of the hash -- a table of placed calls, their attributes, and parameters for sort/filter.

Here is my spec so far.

```
require 'spec_helper'
include Helpers

feature 'Exercise recordings controller' do
  include_context "shared admin context"

  background do
    canned_xml = File.open("spec/support/assets/canned_response.xml").read
    stub_request(:post, "http://recorder.example.com:8080/recorder/index").
      with(body: {"durations"=>["1"], "durations_greater_less"=>["gt"], "filter_from_day"=>"29", "filter_from_hour"=>"0", "filter_from_minute"=>"0", "filter_from_month"=>"12", "filter_from_year"=>"2014", "filter_prefix"=>true, "filter_to_day"=>"29", "filter_to_hour"=>"23", "filter_to_minute"=>"59", "filter_to_month"=>"12", "filter_to_year"=>"2014"}, # "shared_session_id"=>"19f9a08807cc70c1bf41885956695bde"},
           headers: {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Content-Type'=>'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}).
      to_return(status: 200, body: canned_xml, headers: {})
    uri = URI.parse("http://recorder.example.com:8080/recorder/index")
    visit recorded_calls_path
  end

  scenario 'show index page with 1 xml result' do
    #page.save_and_open_page
    expect(title).to eq("Recorded Calls")
  end
end
```

And here is the RecordingsController

```
class RecordingsController < ApplicationController
  # before_filter options
  def index
    test_session_id = request.session_options[:id]
    #Make request to recording app for xml of files
    uri = URI.parse("http://#{Rails.application.config.recorder_server}:#{Rails.application.config.recorder_server_port}/recorder/index")
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    xml_request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
    xml_request_data = Hash.new
    # sorting params
    xml_request_data[:shared_session_id] = request.session_options[:id]
    xml_request.set_form_data(xml_request_data)
    response = http.request(xml_request)
    if response.class == Net::HTTPOK
      @recordings_xml = XmlSimple.xml_in(response.body)
      @recordings_sorted = @recordings_xml["Recording"].sort { |a,b| Time.parse("#{a["date"]} #{a["time"]}") <=> Time.parse("#{b["date"]} #{b["time"]}") } unless @recordings_xml["Recording"].nil?
    else @recordings_xml = Hash.new
    end
  end
  # other defs
end
```

Any and all advice is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## How I configured WebMock

I am answering my own question, with the help of [B-Seven](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27664746/3373470) and a string of comments. File by file, I will list the changes made in order to properly use WebMock.

1. Add WebMock to `Gemfile` under `group :test, :development`.

   - `bundle install` to resolve dependencies
   - my current setup included Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 2.13.0, WebMock 1.17.4
2. Setup `spec_helper.rb` to disable "Real HTTP connections". (This was a backtrace error received later on in this puzzling process.) This allows, to my understanding, all "real connections" to translate into `localhost` connections and work offline... Which is great since, ideally, I do not want the external app's server to run simultaneously.

   ```
   require 'webmock/rspec'
   WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true)
   ```
3. In my `test.rb` environment file, the configurations for `recorder_server` and `port` were commented out... If left uncommented, the controller would raise an exception stating uninitialized constants. I used the test server/port (substituting the company name for `example`) as my layout for the spec stubbing.
4. In `recordings_controller_spec.rb`, I had already figured out how to make a canned XML response. With these changes above, my spec was able to correctly stub a response on an external, secondary app, and use such response to correctly render the view associated with the controller being tested.

   ```
   require 'spec_helper'
   include Helpers

   feature "Exercise recordings_controller" do
     include_context "shared admin context"

     # A background is currently not used, because I have 3 scenario types... No xml
     # results, 1 result, and 2 results. I will later DRY this out with a background,
     # but the heavy lifting is over, for now.

     scenario "show index page with 1 xml result" do
       canned_xml_1 = File.open("spec/support/assets/canned_response_1.xml").read
       stub_request(:post, "http://recorder.example.com:8080/recorder/index").
         with(headers: {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}).
         to_return(status: 200, body: canned_xml_1, headers: {})
       uri = URI.parse("http://recorder.example.com:8080/recorder/index")
       visit recorded_calls_path
       title.should == "Recorded Calls"
       page.should have_content("Search Results")
       page.should have_content("Inbound", "5551230000", "175", "December 24 2014", "12:36:24", "134")
     end

   end
   ```

## Advice/Resources that helped

- With B-Seven's suggestion to my original question (see revisions), I was initially stubbing `localhost:3000`. He said this was incorrect. After further research, I agree since stubbing with WebMock is typically reserved for *outside* http connections.
- In comments after his answer, B-Seven listed articles to refer to. I will list the ones that helped me the most.

  - http://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-stub-external-services-in-tests
  - http://railscasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test
  - https://github.com/bblimke/webmock
  - http://www.agileventures.org/articles/testing-with-rspec-stubs-mocks-factories-what-to-choose
- It is very important to read the backtrace generated from an errors. What took me so long to figure out how to mock was mainly reading them incorrectly. As you can see from my question, I was making a `:get` stub request. A coworker pointed out that the backtrace suggested to use `:post`. That was the final piece to make my spec pass.
- I decided not to input the configuration variables as my stub request, for it would result in long lines of code. Instead, this is why I needed to uncomment out those configurations in `test.rb`.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you stubbing localhost? I think you want to

```
stub_request(:get, "http://#{Rails.application.config.recorder_server}:#{Rails.application.config.recorder_server_port}/recorder/index").
```

Comment: Thank you. The `test.rb` file has these configurations commented out. Do i need to define them in that file before stubbing?

Comment: It looks like the config is set up correctly. It is making the request to example.com, which is good. So you should stub_request example.com or `Rails.application.config.recorder_server`. I think the latter is better.

Comment: However, WebMock does not seem to be working. It looks like you need to use `WebMock.disable_net_connect!`. Which version of WebMock are you using?

Comment: It looks like the WebMock version is OK. You need to use `disable_net_connect!` and `stub_request` before running the spec. First `disable_net_connect!` and it should tell you the HTTP request it wants to make. Then you will know exactly what to stub.

Comment: In `spec_helper.rb`, I have `WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow: "http://recorder.example.com:8080")`. I am getting `A WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError occurred in recordings#index: Real HTTP connections are disabled.` error, even after following the suggested `stub_request`. I have the stub request in my spec's background. Is what I am trying to accomplish actually possible with WebMock alone?

Comment: Yes. The reason the error is being raised is because the stub_request does not match the request *exactly* or it is after the request is being made. Looking at your code, it seems that the stub_request location is good. You are mocking localhost but requesting www.example.com. These have to match.

Comment: I am on the Android app, and will update my question when i reach a computer. At the moment, i changed the block in `spec_helper.rb` and my spec to contain `recorder.example.com:8080/recorder/index`. .... I feel like I'm just missing some integral understanding of stubs and mocks, even after reading a dozen articles and following your advice on this question.

Comment: Funny, I was thinking the same thing. I suggest doing a tutorial on WebMock so you can understand how it works outside of your app. Have you seen this one? http://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-stub-external-services-in-tests

Comment: Also, you may find this book helpful: https://pragprog.com/book/nrtest2/rails-4-test-prescriptions

Comment: Thought bot actually helped me understand a lot... I modeled my spec after theirs, since it was the only tutorial i found online that showed WebMock inside a spec file. I'm going to reread your suggestions today and tomorrow. I gladly appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm going to mark this post as the answer. Although the post itself didn't help, the comments are the best part

Comment: OK, thanks. I suggest going through some RSpec tutorials so you can understand how testing works outside of your app. For example, here is one that will hopefully make sense to you: http://railscasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test. I highly recommend RailsCasts as a source of info.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67917/discussion-between-onebree-and-b-seven).